# Is it possible to update a session variable using a form in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a form that should allow users to update a session variable called `session[:city]` that tracks their location. The variable doesn't need to be saved in the database cause it's kind of a throwaway; it only needs to exist while the user is on the site.

`session[:city]` is used in several places throughout the site, so I've placed the following method in the Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_city

  def set_city
    unless session[:city].present?
      session[:city] = request.location.city
    end
    if params[:city].present?
      session[:city] = params[:city]
    end
  end
end
```

That part works correctly, and I'm able to call the variable throughout the site.

The issue I'm having is in updating the variable by a form. The only action I need it to do is update the variable, but it's not responding. I know I'm missing something here, but after trying a bunch of things I'm a bit stumped. This is my basic form currently:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :city, params[:city] %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

**Edited to working code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions needed to be split into 2 statements: an unless to set the session[:city] and an if to check if any params were being passed.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_city

  def set_city
    unless session[:city].present?
      session[:city] = request.location.city
    end
    if params[:city].present?
      session[:city] = params[:city]
    end
  end
end
```

And the working form:

```
<%= form_tag root_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :city, params[:city], :placeholder => "#{session[:city]}: Change City" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will not work in production like environment where you have multiple worker process to serve the requests(unicorn or passenger). Each process will have its own memory. If the value is changed during a request processed by one worker process, other processes will not have the updated value.

You should be using session to store this information.

Comment: If I replaced all `@city` instances with `session[:city]` will that work in a production environment? Am I able to update the session variable through a user submitted form?

Comment: No. Pass it as a parameter to controller and set the session in the controller

Comment: That makes my form work for a single page, but it loses the value as soon as I navigate away. Is there something I'm missing with the session variable so it carries on throughout the site?

Comment: When you put some value in the session, it is available until the session ends. So you will be able to access the variable in all your pages. You can read it as session[:city]. When you want to change the value, change it in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:-

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :person, :city, :name => "city" %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_city

  def set_city
    unless session[:city].present?
      session[:city] = params[:city] || request.location.city
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm. I got the `set_city` method working using your code when I removed the unless statement so the logic would be session[:city] is equal to the user's params or the requested location. The problem is, I still need the form to update session[:city] when a param is passed in. It doesn't seem to store the update for more than one page.

Comment: I am confused how are you getting request.location.city. Probably when you dont submit the form it is set to nil by request.location.city

Comment: Ah. The if/else/unless statements are reassigning the variable. So I need to write something that will get the `request.location` by default, and override the `session[:city]` if `params[:city]` has been entered.

Comment: request.location.city is a method from RubyGeocoder that gets the location by IP address.

Comment: The conditions needed to be split into 2 statements: an unless to set the session[:city] and an if to check if any params were being passed. Thanks for your help!